# Can't set video.currentTime by setting video.currentTime = {value}

Tags: javascript, html, video

In this piece of code I have `video.currentTime = {value}`
And it works fine.

But when I'm trying to reload the page by pressing `Crtl+Shift+R` it sets `video.currentTime` to **`0`**, no matter when on the progress bar I clicked. 
Why is that?

```
window.addEventListener('load', function(){

var video = document.getElementById('video');
var playButton = document.getElementById('play-button');
var pbar = document.getElementById('pbar');
var update;
var pbarContainer = document.getElementById('pbar-container');

video.load();
video.addEventListener('canplay', function(){
    playButton.addEventListener('click', playOrPause, false);
    pbarContainer.addEventListener('click', skip, false);
}, false);

var skip = function(ev) {
    var mouseX = ev.pageX - pbarContainer.offsetLeft;
    var width = window.getComputedStyle(pbarContainer).getPropertyValue('width');
    width = parseFloat(width.substr(0, width.length - 2));

    video.currentTime = (mouseX/width)*video.duration;
};


var updatePlayer = function() {
    var percentage = (video.currentTime/video.duration)*100;
    pbar.style.width = percentage + '%';
    if(video.ended) {
        window.clearInterval(update);
        playButton.src = 'images/replay.png';
    }
};

var playOrPause = function(){

    if(video.paused) {
        video.play();
        playButton.src = 'images/pause.png';
        update = setInterval(updatePlayer, 30);
    } else {
        video.pause();
        playButton.src = 'images/play.png';
        window.clearInterval(update);
    }
};

//video.addEventListener('click', playOrPause(playButton), false);
}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refreshing your page stops all execution of your code and resets all your variables, basically starting you from the beginning.

If you want variables to remain even after refreshing the page then set the localStorage and your values will be saved on the browser. You can find them if you open your developer tools in the Resources section under localStorage:

`localStorage.setItem(video.currentTime,value)`

To retrieve it, you'll have to use

`localStorage.getItem(video.currentTime,value)`